# Tensorflow `map_fn` takes long time to execute

Tags: python, tensorflow, mapping, tensorflow2.0

Given tensors `a` of shape `(n, f)` and `b` of shape `(m, f)`, I have created a function to calculate euclidean distances between these two tensors

```
import tensorflow as tf

nr = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(a), 1)
nw = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(b), 1)

nr = tf.reshape(nr, [-1, 1])
nw = tf.reshape(nw, [1, -1])
res = nr - 2*tf.matmul(a, b, False, True) + nw
res = tf.argmin(res, axis=1)
```

So far so good, the code runs slightly fast (I got better performance with `cKDTree`, when `n= 1000, m=1600, f=4`, but this is not the issue now). I will check the performance versus different input sizes later.

In this example the `b` tensor is a rank 2, flattened version of a rank 3 tensor. I do that to be able to evaluate the euclidean distances using two tensors with same rank (that is simpler). But after evaluate the distances I need to know where on the original tensor each one of the nearest elements are. For that I have created the custom lambda function `fn` to convert back to the rank 3 tensor coordinates.

```
fn = lambda x: (x//N, x%N)
# This map takes a enormous amount of time
out = tf.map_fn(fn, res, dtype=(tf.int64, tf.int64))
return tf.stack(out, axis=1)
```

But sadly this `tf.map_fn` takes a **HUGE** time to run, around **300ms**.

Just for comparison, if I perform a `np.apply_along_axis` in a dataset that exacly the same data (but a numpy array)  the footprint is barely noticiable, around 50 microseconds vs. 300ms of tensorflow equivalent.

There are better approaches in tensorflow for this `mapping`?

TF version 2.1.0 and CUDA is enabled and working.

Just to add some timings

```
%timeit eucl_dist_tf_vecmap(R_tf, W_tf)
28.1 ms ± 128 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)


%timeit eucl_dist_tf_nomap(R_tf, W_tf)
2.07 ms ± 122 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


%timeit eucl_dist_ckdtree_applyaxis(R, W)  
878 µs ± 2.34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit eucl_dist_ckdtree_noapplyaxis(R, W)  
817 µs ± 51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The first two timings are using the custom function shown here, the first one with `vectorized_map` and the second one without `vectorized_map` and the `stack` (the overhead is on `vectorized_map`, tested.

And the last two times is an implementations based on scipy's `cKDTree`. The first one uses `np.apply_along_axis` exactly as used in vectorized map. We can see that overhead is much smaller in the numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try tf.vectorized_map. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/vectorized_map

If you need to change de data type, you can try to change parallel_iterations value in map_fn params, that is set to 1 by default in eager mode.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and thank you for the answer. Indeed `vectorized_map` gave a better timing result, but still too slow. It adds *26ms*, while `np.apply_along_axis` add only 50 micro seconds, 500x faster.

Comment: It seems a problem with implementation. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24774

In TF 2.x you can use numpy operations instead.